# My PC only suspends and hibernate when I enter a terminal

Tags: system-installation, system, suspend

I installed Elementary OS with the newest version and something is wrong with it. I can't suspend my computer and I dont know why.. I can only suspend it if I open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+F1 and login. If I do this, it works. Otherwise it wont..

Does anyone know's what's happening?

Comment: Could  you share some system information? Maybe a screenshot of System Settings > About or the output of Neofetch.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to subtle mouse movement waking up your machine when suspending from a desktop. See [here](http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1985) for instructions on how to prevent this from happening.

If that doesn't help, some more info would be helpful:

- How are you suspending? By the closing the laptop lid or via a menu or command?
- What do you mean when you say suspending "doesn't work"? Does it suspend and immediately wake up again? Does nothing happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: I think Josh is on the correct path here. I had an issue kind of close to this and solved it. Here's a link to my question/answer: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/suspend-behavior-on-hp-laptop